# How to write an Excel formula, counting multiple cells that match multiple criteria

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to write an Excel formula that counts multiple criteria for the multiple units in my group and have exhausted my Google skills. I'm using COUNTIFS but I've run into a snag with my second criteria. Here is my formula.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Master!$M$2:Master!$M$5000,$A2,Master!$K$2:Master!$K$5000,{"Advisor","Chaplain","Liaison","Treasurer","Committee Chairperson"}))`

The first criteria first matches the individual units we have in our group by referencing $A2. This gives a count of all of the adults in a particular unit like AK-0225 or WA-0034.

The second criteria then matches specific leaders in that unit based on the job title. This formula works but we have several leaders who hold multiple roles so the formula is counting someone that only holds say the role of Treasurer, but if their role actually says "Service Chairperson, Treasurer" it's not picking it up because it's not an exact match. How do I fix this?

Just for context, I will be using a third counting later in the formula once I get this issue resolved. The third will count another range to find out if they've attended available training.

Comment: Add a wildcard before and after each term: `"*Advisor*", "*Chaplain*", etc.` This does assume that no leader has multiple roles from that list, e.g. you never have a leader who is `Adviser, Treasurer` for example.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah that might be a possibility that one leader might be wearing the Chaplain and Liaison hat

Comment: Which now that I think about it, that will work anyway. If one leader is wearing 2 hats, the formula will pick them up and count them. I'll just have another column that counts the leadership and if there is 1 less than the expected, divide by a lesser number to determine the percentage. Thanks for the help.